# jquery to find last td of last tr for adding new tr when click on last td

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement when am click on last td of last tr i want to append new row.here tr are dynamic not fixed.

```
$('#item_table tr:last-child td:last-child').click(function(){
```

above code is not working for my requirement.

Comment: Where is the code which appends the new row? Is it that which is failing, or the selector? In either case we can't really debug the problem without seeing a more complete example of your code

Comment: $('#item_table tr:last-child td:last-child') is correct

Comment: thanks for reply $('#item_table tr:last-child td:last-child') it's working now.

Comment: after adding new tr it's not taking new row td as last td is their any logic please help